# How to save multiple form in the same table like phpmyadmin

Tags: cakephp

I'm working with CakePHP version 2.3

I've been wondering how to save a looped form like phpmyadmin does when you input multiple form for 1 table.

Let's say that I have a table products with id, name and content columns.
In order to save my data, I make a form with this 3 inputs multiplied by 3.
So that gives me something like this :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Product'); ?>

<!-- Form for product 1 -->
<?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => "Name")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('content', array('label' => "Content")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('id'); ?>

<!-- Form for product 2 -->
<?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => "Name")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('content', array('label' => "Content")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('id'); ?>

<!-- Form for product 3 -->
<?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => "Name")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('content', array('label' => "Content")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('id'); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end('done'); ?>
```

Of course this can't work and I have no clue to how to get this done.

Does anybody could show me how it works?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following calls to `input()` method:

```
...
echo $this->Form->input('Product.0.name', array('label' => 'Name'));
echo $this->Form->input('Product.0.content', array('label' => 'Content'));

echo $this->Form->input('Product.1.name', array('label' => 'Name'));
echo $this->Form->input('Product.1.content', array('label' => 'Content'));

echo $this->Form->input('Product.2.name', array('label' => 'Name'));
echo $this->Form->input('Product.2.content', array('label' => 'Content'));
...
```

The previous code should output the following form elements

```
<input type="text" id="Product0name" name="data[Product][0][name]">
<input type="teaxtarea" id="Product0Content" name="data[Product][0][Content]">

<input type="text" id="Product1name" name="data[Product][1][name]">
<input type="teaxtarea" id="Product1Content" name="data[Product][1][Content]">

<input type="text" id="Product2name" name="data[Product][2][name]">
<input type="teaxtarea" id="Product2Content" name="data[Product][2][Content]">
```

which can posted and saved by your controller using `saveAll()` method very easily.
Also check out the CakePHP docs at: [Field-naming-conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions)

Comment: This is the best approach, although I think there should also be a (hidden) input for the product-id when editing existing products

Comment: @Cris Sawfish: I saw you removed the id input but i will obviously need it because every 3 input (including id) it's a new product. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks for your suggestion anyway, I'm gonna try that today.

TO thaJeztah: I don't see the point having a hidden input for a product_id column knowing that i already have an id column. It's got the same purpose in that case, right?

What if I want the same system but with the possibility to choose how many row i want, exactly like phpmyadmin?

Comment: @JulianLivin'inChina When creating a form for **adding** data to the database, you don't have to create an `input` element in your forms. The id is created automaticaly with respect to the schema of the table. So no matter how many items you save at once, since you follow the posted convention, cakephp handles the rest. As theJeztah pointed, you only need an `input` for the `id` only when you are editing a specific entry.

Comment: @Cris Sawfish: Ok I see now, it's good that i followed cakePHP conventions then. I openned a new topic for a related problem, if you feel like cheking it, i'd really appreciated it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953015/cakephp-2-3-save-multiple-forms-in-multiple-tables-all-at-once-in-1-page.<br/>
Thank you for all your help anyway!